# How to create a container below circle avatar that has a custom shape cut out at top?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve this layout in flutter:

[image]

First widget is a Circle Avatar. The other is a container. I'm pretty new to flutter so I don't know how I could go about achieving this. Stack would not work as the background would not be visible:

[image]

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
        foregroundImage: _getImage(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

How can I achieve this effect? The only solution I found was to put a transparent png image but that wouldn't work as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I spent my whole day doing this research. But I think I got what you wanted.

Try this, if not, tell me exactly where the problem is and I'll try to fix it.

Edit : Reloading is not possible with hot reload.

```
Center(
        child: PersonCard(
          height: 150,
          width: 250,
          avatarRadius: 30,
          avatarChild: const Icon(Icons.person),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Widget;

```
  class PersonCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
    this.avatarMargin,
    required this.avatarRadius,
    this.avatarChild,
    this.avatarBgColor = Colors.grey,
    this.decoration,
    this.child,
    this.widgetBgColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double? avatarMargin;
  final double avatarRadius;
  final Widget? avatarChild;
  final Color avatarBgColor;
  final Color widgetBgColor;
  final BoxDecoration? decoration;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  State<PersonCard> createState() => _PersonCardState();
}

class _PersonCardState extends State<PersonCard> {
  late final double holeRadius;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.avatarMargin == null) {
      holeRadius = widget.avatarRadius * 2.5;
    } else {
      holeRadius = (widget.avatarRadius * 2.5) + widget.avatarMargin!;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        ClipPath(
          clipper: NotchClipper(
            context: context,
            holeRadius: holeRadius,
            width: widget.width,
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            color: widget.decoration == null ? widget.widgetBgColor : null,
            decoration: widget.decoration,
            child: widget.child,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: -(widget.avatarRadius),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: widget.avatarRadius,
            backgroundColor: widget.avatarBgColor,
            child: widget.avatarChild,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Clipper;

```
class NotchClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  NotchClipper({required this.holeRadius, required this.context, required this.width});

  final BuildContext context;
  final double holeRadius;
  final double width;

  double get right {
    return (width - holeRadius) / 2;
  }

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right - holeRadius, 0.0)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - right, 0),
        clockwise: false,
        radius: const Radius.circular(4),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right, size.height);

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(NotchClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: The edges where the clipped path ends are sharp. Any way to make them rounded like in the image I provided?  That's the only problem else the solution works like a charm!